# Why does async extension method throw System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, extension-methods

I have two extension methods, that pretty much do the same thing but one is async

```
public static class ProjectExtensions
{
   public static Layout GetLayout(this Project project)
   {
      ..
   }

   public static async Task<Layout> GetLayoutAsync(this Project project)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

And I'm using the `.?` operator because I don't want to call these methods if the project is null:

```
public async Task<Layout> GetMapFrameLocator()
{    
   Project currentProject = Project.Current;             // this can be null
   var layout1 = await currentProject?.GetLayoutAsync(); // throws!
   var layout2 = currentProject?.GetLayout();            // works fine
}
```

Neither methods actually get called, which I expected, but the async one throws a null reference exception which doesnt make sense to me because nothing gets called with the null `Project`. I know this issue will go away if I use `.` instead of `.?` and handle the null parameter in the static extension method, but whats the reason this for this exception and why is the async method different?

Comment: You're currently effectively doing `await (Task<Layout>) null;` and that isn't going to work well...

Comment: Your code is essentially `Task<Layout> layout1 = await null;` and you can't await null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`await` requires a `Task` to await.

If your `currentProject` is null then the expression `currentProject?.GetLayoutAsync()` will resolve to null. await cannot await null